# The 7th message in the Kerberos protocol and ticket validation

Tags: java, kerberos

I'm developing a simple [Kerberos protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) for a project. However, I've come across some questions to which I can't find an anwser.

The fifth message in the protocol. From the client, C, to the server, S, is as follows:

{C, t}<sub>K<sub>CS</sub></sub>, {C, S, tstart, tend, K<sub>CS</sub>}<sub>K<sub>S</sub></sub>, {Request, n<sub>3</sub>}<sub>K<sub>CS</sub></sub>

The sixth message in the protocol, from the server, S, to the client, C, is as follows:

{Reply, n<sub>3</sub>}<sub>K<sub>CS</sub></sub>

How does the seventh message look like? Or in other words, when I want to make another request to the server, do I need to include the authenticator and ticket again? If not, how does the server validate the ticket?

Comment: It is just the way I phrased it. The Kerberos protocol simply put, has 6 messages. The first two are client asking the authentication server for a TGS ticket, and the response from the authentication server with the ticket. The next two messages are the client asking the TGS for the server ticket, and the TGS response with the server ticket. Finally the last two (5th and 6th) are the client making a request to the server and the server response. This request contains the ticket. And my question is if the subsequent requests also contain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every request to the server must be accompanied by the service ticket, which is the only means of verifying the authenticity of that particular request. The additional *Authenticator*, unique for each request, is also needed to prevent replay attacks.